# Autofocus on button with angular2+

Tags: html, angular, button, focus, angular6

I currently working on a new webapplication where I have an `input` for some text. If the text is not valid, a `div` will popup and show an information.  In this `div` I have a `button` which closes the popup but this `button` is not focused. I tried `<button autofocus></<button>`. The problem of `autofocus` is, that it focus only once when the pace refreshs.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that problem?

Here is my unfinished code (popup):

```
<div class="modal__body">
      <p [innerHTML]="'Question.IncorrectNotification' | translate:{value: (policy?.maxTriesBeforeTimeout - userService?.trialNumber)}"></p>
      <div class="button-group flex-items-xs-center">
          <button autofocus (click)="closeIncorrectAnswerDialog()" class="button button--primary">
                {{ 'Question.OkButton' | translate }}
          </button>
      </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: autofocus only use for input so you cant use for button

Comment: @NgôHùngPhúc it works for buttons too, I tested it

Comment: Use `<form>` and give button as `Submit` then it will always be focused.